# local databases for storing strings in java desktop application, currently using MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, sqlite, database

I am currently working on a project in which I am storing the name of program/application window titles and my knowledge of databases and datastores is fairly limited.

The idea is that I want to query the database with a string to see if it is present in the database. I am currently using MongoDB to do this but I have seen that MongoDB is mostly used to be run on a server which isn't what I'm looking for.

My question is - if I am just storing strings / searching for strings would a custom Array or HashMap be sufficient or would search times make it inefficient meaning that SQLite would be more ideal for this situation.

Comment: Start simple. See what works without introducing external dependencies like SQL (or NoSQL). A Hash of some sort would make for extremely efficient matching and would be extremely easy to manage. Designed correctly, you can switch to a more robust solution later.

Comment: Yes, there would be a huge performance difference between the two. Using an Array might cause you to search through every item worst case, but with a sorted array, and the right search algo, it's not bad. But, a Hash is likely to give you very good consistent results. If Java doesn't offer just a plain "Hash" (where it's just a key hash and no associated value), then it's not terrible choice by any means. A little extra storage for each entry. But, at some point you may have some extra data. It should be faster than using SQLite -- as there just aren't as many moving parts. :)

Comment: I get sooo tired of seeing these CLOSED messages. Is there a place other than Stack overflow where opinions can be asked instead of being censored here? If it turns into a flame war, then yes close it. But I don't see that here. I truly would like to hear everyone's opinion before making my own. Why is that a problem for the Stack Overflow Censors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is perfect for this application.  Firefox, for example, uses SQLite for storing its internal configuration settings (the `about:config` page). SQLite databases are single files, and it can be transparent to the user and requires very little in the way of system resources--unlike most server/client database solutions.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to use java preferences api, if the data to be saved is not too much and if it needs to be available even when the application is terminated and restarted.,